# Decrease pointer until it points to the first element of array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory

I use `*ptr` to iterate a char array from end to beginning (one byte at the time) and set some values in the way. When the pointer points to the  first address the algorithm should stop.

```
  char *buf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 3 + 1);
  char *ptr = &buf[sizeof buf - 1]; // *ptr point to the last address
  *ptr = '\0';

  do {
    if(alfa) {
      *(--ptr) = "teststring"[alfa]; // *ptr decreases value by one
      alfa -= i;
    } else { *(--ptr) = 'N'; }
  } while(*ptr != &buf[0]); // should check if *ptr is now pointing to the start of buf. If that's the case, stop.
```

But, after it check the addresses are equal, it gives me:

```
** stack smashing detected **: <unknown> terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Another (and maybe relatable) thing is: malloc should allocate 4 bytes from memory, but when I check `sizeof(buf)` it has 8 bytes(?).

Note: The output of `sizeof(char) * 3 + 1` is indeed 4. But it's not the same as `sizeof(buf)`.

Comment: `sizeof buf` doesn't give you what you think it does. It returns the size of the *pointer* `buf`, not what it points to. Incidentally this will still work on 32-bit systems where pointers are four bytes. It will *not* work very well on a 64-bit system where pointers are 8 bytes (as you noticed).

Comment: Please don't use `malloc`/`free` in a C++ program. Use `new`/`delete`. Or even better; use smart pointers (`make_unique`, `make_shared` and friends) and STL containers (like `std::array` and `std::vector`). Your current code reads as "C compiled with a C++ compiler" - you can do better than that.

Comment: How is `alfa` defined and initialised?

Comment: @alk alfa is an int number

Comment: ...  and initialised?

Comment: Same questions applie to `i`.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof some_variable` evaluates to the size of a variable.

So this `sizeof buf` evaluates  to the size of `buf`. With `buf` being a pointer it gives you either 4 or 8 depending whether the code is compiled on a 32 or 64 bit platform.

To fix your problem change this

```
  char *buf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 3 + 1);
  char *ptr = &buf[sizeof buf - 1];
```

to this

```
  size_t size = sizeof(char) * 3 + 1;
  char *buf = malloc(size); /* No need to cast void-pointer sin C. */
  char *ptr = &buf[size - 1]; // *ptr point to the last address
```

Taking into account that `sizeof (char)` equals `1` by definition just do:

```
  size_t size = 3 + 1;
  char *buf = malloc(size); 
  char *ptr = &buf[size - 1];
```

Comment: Thank you. I now understand why it is giving me 8 (instead of four) and corrected it.

However, my code still gives me an error with "stack smashing detected" after comparing both addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is right, but also, your last test:

```
while(*ptr != &buf[0]);
```

Isn't checking that `ptr` is not at the first position in the buffer.  That would be `ptr != &buf[0]` or just `ptr != buf`.

You are seeing if the data at pointer (`*ptr`) is unequal to the the location of the beginning of the buffer, thereby comparing a char to a pointer.  Your compiler is probably giving you a warning about it.  Don't ignore warnings in C.